npm windows-build-tools Specify python version to use
I need to install windows-build-tools with offline installers
From the documentation Here
(

By default, windows-build-tools will download the latest installers from Microsoft each time it's installed. Alternatively, you can prepare a folder that contains installers. They need to have their original names:
Visual Studio Build Tools: vs_BuildTools.exe or BuildTools_Full.exe
Python: python-3.8.1.amd64.msi or python-3.8.1.msi
Then, run windows-build-tools with the --offline-installers argument:

)
I use the command npm install -g windows-build-tools --offline-installers="C:\local"
And located python-3.8.6-amd64.exe vs_BuildTools.exe under this path.
But when installing its looking for other version of python:
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./dist/index.js
npm error Offline installation: Offline path C:\local was passed, but we could not find python-2.7.14.amd64.msi in that path. Aborting installation now.

How can I specify the version of python it should take.
Note:
I know the best practice is to re-install nodejs and check to install build-tools during installation, But Im working on a project that other team members could clone and I don`t want them to have to re-install node.
I want to create a script doing all the work
